# RxJava CompletableSubject toFlowable/ toObservable doesn't emit

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

So I have a producer/ publisher that is CompletableSubject

I want a read-only version of that for the subscribers/ observers to use
but neither `toFLowable()` nor `toObservable` is emitting anything

What am I missing?

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val publisher = CompletableSubject.create()

    val readOnlyStream = publisher.toFlowable<Any>()

    println("1 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")
    readOnlyStream.subscribe { item ->
        println("yay, got it $item")
    }

    println("2 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")
    publisher.onComplete()
    println("3 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")

    Thread.sleep(3000L)
}
```

outputs:

```
1 false
2 false
3 true
```

Weird workaround I found

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val publisher = CompletableSubject.create()

    val readOnlyStream = publisher.toSingle {
        "doneee"
    }

    println("1 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")
    readOnlyStream.subscribe { item ->
        println("yay, got it $item")
    }

    println("2 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")
    publisher.onComplete()
    println("3 ${publisher.hasComplete()}")

    Thread.sleep(3000L)
}
```

outputs:

```
1 false
2 false
yay, got it doneee
3 true
```

Comment: CompletableSubject can only terminate thus and has no notion of onNext. Therefore, you have to inject a value upon its termination. toSingle does this.

Comment: @akarnokd, thanks. A team member of mine was doing `completableSubject.subscribe {}` which means the consumer/ observer can mistakenly cause termination regardless of the publisher. I can't help but feel it's rather inconsistent with other type of Subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As akarnokd said in the comments, the `readOnlyStream.subscribe { item ->` is adding a callback for an item, and an item was never emitted.
However that does not mean that the onComplete event was not propagated to the Flowable. The onComplete event can be subscribed like this:

```
readOnlyStream.subscribe(
    {}, // onNext, called for each item
    {}, // onError, called once when there is an error
    { println("yay, got onComplete") }, // onComplete, called once when completed
)
```

The completableSubject's subscribe method does not have the onNext method since Completables don't emit any items, only onError or onComplete events.